# BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfType vs BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors in spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Having this class:

```
public interface DeviceRule {
}
```

and this

```
@Service(value = "androidRule")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class AndroidRule implements DeviceRule {
..
}
```

this method is working fine called in a service, getting AndroidRule

```
Map<?, DeviceRule> map = BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(context, DeviceRule.class, true, false);
```

but not this one:

```
BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfType(context, AndroidRule.class, true, false);
```

as I got this error:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'androidRule' must be of type [com.devices.AndroidRule], but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy302]:org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException:Bean named 'androidRule' must be of type [com.devices.AndroidRule], but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy302]
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a `@Transactional` annotation to a class, spring creates a proxy for that, in order to enhance it with begin, commit and rollback.

When you invoke the `BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfType`, it tries to return a unique bean of the given type. And in your case, there are two (including the proxy). Therefore, it fails.

Can you check how many beans, the `BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors` returns.

Comment: all beans that implements DeviceRule